# strange similarity result in spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I am playing around with the similarity function in Spacy and observed something that I dont understand:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  
doc1 = nlp("Honda Civic Toyota")
doc2 = nlp("Honda Civic Toyota car Christian God")

for token in doc1:
    print (token.text, doc1[0].similarity(token))
for token in doc2:
    print (token.text, doc2[0].similarity(token))
```

Output:

```
Honda 1.0
Civic 0.6631208
Toyota 0.4700994
Honda 1.0
Civic 0.6806056
Toyota 0.54713947
car 0.22469836
Christian 0.5016042
God 0.4778438
```

The word Honda is being compared to all the other words in doc1 and doc2 and it can be observed that when Honda is compared with Civic and Toyota, the similarity is different in doc1 and doc2.
My understanding is that the similarity is computed from the consine similarity of the Glove vector of the words, which is loaded from 'en_core_web_sm'. If that is the case, shouldn't the similarity between the same pair of words the same regardless of its context?

I think clearly I am misunderstanding something, would appreciate it if someone could clarify on it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Word Vectors and Semantic  Similarity](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity) Doc:

> Similarity is determined by comparing word vectors or "word embeddings", multi-dimensional meaning representations of a word.To make them compact and fast, spaCy's small models (all packages that
>   end in sm) don't ship with word vectors, and only include
>   context-sensitive tensors. This means you can still use the
>   `similarity()` methods to compare documents, spans and tokens – but the
>   result won't be as good, and individual tokens won't have any vectors
>   assigned.So in order to use real word vectors, you need to download a larger model

so small models don't use word vectors for similarity.